# How does S3 make public URLs unique

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

I have a bucket named video. I am making one of its objects 'cool.mp4' public.

now the object URL becomes: https://video.s3.ap-south-1.amazonaws.com/cool.mp4

And downloading this works.
My question is, what will happen if some one in the same region has a bucket video and has a file named cool.mp4. How will S3 differentiate the two public URLs.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Based on the [doc](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/UsingBucket.html), bucket name should be globally unique.

> An Amazon S3 bucket name is globally unique, and the namespace is shared by all AWS accounts.

In other words, there shouldn't exist two buckets with the same name.

Comment: Thanks. [More Info](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/BucketRestrictions.html)